# Springframework and @Value with placeholder

Tags: java, spring

I have an annotated service in a jar, which is included in a webapp.

The service has some properties valued by the @Value annotation, which uses placeolders. 
The property-placeholder is defined in the webapp, not in the jar.
My problem is that at runtime placeholders are not resolved.

This is an example. In the JAR:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
   @Value("${property.myvalue}")
   private myValue;
}
```

In the WAR applicationContext:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myprops.properties"/>
```

Naturally myprops.properties exists in the war and it is loaded (I tried to remove it and I obtain an explicit file not found error).

Moreover, unit test with a myprops.properties in the test classpath passed.

Is there a classpath issue?

Comment: Where is the file myprops.properties ? inside /WEB-INF/classes ?

Comment: Make sure that you aren't creating 2 instances of the same service. If you have a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` make sure you aren't component-scanning the same packages twice. a `property-placeholder` will only work for beans in the same application context. So if you have this in your `ContextLoaderListener` those will be replaced, but not the for the beans in the `DispatcherServlet` and vice-versa.